# Laravel 5: Returning simple data in controllers

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have an API controller, where I always return JSON. Returned status will always be 200, because for other cases I'm throwing exceptions and handle them globally. I used to `return response()->json($content);` in each controller's method, but I changed it to form JSON in the middleware. Now, I'm having `return response($content);` everywhere. I was thinking about simplifying it even more and just `return $content;` instead. It works, but I am not sure if it's reasonable solution.

Are there any traps behind this idea?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a good solution since you are using a middleware. In routes you don't want to return data as JSON you can simply exclude them from running your middleware.

In the future if you want to return your data in another format you can even pass the format as an argument when running the middleware. For example:

```
Route::get('resource/{id}', ['middleware' => 'format:xml', function ($id) {
    //
}]);
```